# Lookup Condition in Informatica for double and decimal datatype

Tags: etl, informatica, sqldatatypes, informatica-powercenter

I have a lookup table which have column name 'Serial_Number' in double format and source table (SQ) Serial_Number in double format. How both table can be connected in the lookup condition?

I am trying to create lookup condition with both serial number to get another information from the lookup table. What is the difference between decimal and double datatype? how they can be connected in lookup?

Answer (score 1):

The transformation Decimal datatype supports precision  of up to 28 digits and the Double datatype supports precision of up to  15 digits.
`decimal(p,s) - Precision 1 to 28 digits, scale 0 to 28`
`double - Precision 1 to 15 digits, scale 0 to 15`

So, if you use double instead of decimal, there can be some data loss in precision.

I would recommend to join on decimal data type in lookup because its superset and there will be no chance of loss of precision.

Comment: I'll add that double is not precise. It's just an approximation, so some numbers are not stored exactly as they are. It's best to avoid double - it's meand only for cases where lack of precision is not a concern.

Comment: to be precise - `double can double cross you` ;) be careful